# Disable WindowedApplication Resize in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I'm trying to make it so the WindowedApplication in Flex is not resizable.  However, resizable is a read-only public variable for the class.

How do I make it so the user cannot resize the Flex application (running in Adobe Air)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in Flex how do I make a window not resizable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797398/in-flex-how-do-i-make-a-window-not-resizable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your project is called `foo` a `foo-app.xml` will also be automatically generated. This is an application configuration file. Edit this file, in particular change:

```
<!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
<!-- <resizable></resizable> -->
```

to:

```
<!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
<resizable>false</resizable>
```

(Note: This property is commented out typically and the default value is true.)

Comment: It's weird that they just didn't make the WindowedApplication object have a writeable resizabe property.  Thanks for this answer dirkgently, you saved me a lot of head scratching.

Answer (score -1):

To make the main window application such that it can neither be resized nor be maximized, then go to the src folder of your application in Flash Builder and open **your-application-name-app.xml** file. (This is the app config file of your project.) Now make the following adjustments to the maximizable and resizable properties in this file:

```
<maximizable>false</maximizable>
<resizable>false</resizable>
```

Comment: Your answer is less succinct than the existing one, refers to another question & answer, and doesn't add any value here.  Additionally, your link is currently broken.