# in Flex how do I make a window not resizable?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

So I'm trying to open a second window that is meant to be a fixed size window. I've set resizable property to false but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

here's my sample code

Main app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       height="600"
                       creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import foo.TestWindow;

            protected function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                var window:TestWindow = new TestWindow();
                window.open();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

TestWindow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Window xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300"
          resizable="false">

    <s:Label text="this window should not be resizable" />
</s:Window>
```

When I run this code, my expectation is that TestWindow should not be resizable. however I can resize it without any problem. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked fine for me (i.e., no resizing on the TestWindow instance), using Flex 4.1.  Has to be something other than what you've presented thus far.  Could you supply some details about your environment and/or compiler settings?  Are you changing things in the Application Descriptor File, like turn on system chrome?

Comment: I agree with merv, show up the descriptor file.  Plus, if all else fails, disabling system chrome will definitely stop it.

Comment: I didn't change any settings. I created a new flex project so I can isolate the issue. so I wonder why it worked for you.. well setting maximizable to false solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Flash Builder 4.5 and the root tag is `s:WindowedApplication` *not* `s:Window` as you said; and there is no property named 'resizable'.
While I was looking for a better solution, I just found this. Hope will help you:
http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/16-code-for-a-resizable-window-in-as3

Here is a very simple solution:
Go to the src folder of your application and open HalloFlex-app.xml file. This is the app config file and make following adjustments to the maximizable and resizable properties in this file:

```
<maximizable>false</maximizable>  
<resizable>false</resizable>
```

This way your app window will neither be resizable and nor be maximizable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok i figured it out. You need to also set maximizable property to false as well for this to work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that isn't working but you could try to set maxWidth, minWidth, maxHeight, and minHeight.